# Electron-react logic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, electron

I'm new to Web development and trying to develop an application that uses Electron and react-redux framework. I'm a little confused on how things work logically.

In particular, I'm not sure of what processes are rendered processes when we run an electron app which uses React components. For example, if I have a file named `main.tsx` that is the main process and loads `index.html` which is linked to `app.tsx`. In a non-react framework, `app.tsx` will be the rendered process, but now since `app.tsx` just contains a react component, can I use it as a rendered process. In other words, is it possible to have communication between `main.tsx` and `app.tsx` with ipcMain and ipcRender?

P.S: I might have used poor terms to describe the question, but any replies would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: Unsure of your exact question, but anything that would normally be loaded via the index.html should go in the rendered process. React / Angular, any front-end framework lives in the renderer process.